# Why is the base class of `plugin` between Play 1 and Play 2 so different?

Tags: plugins, playframework, playframework-2.0

The plugin base class in [Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_Framework) 1, is `play.PlayPlugin`, which has a lot of methods (fields):

```
index : int
onLoad()
compileSources()
runTest(Class<BaseTest>)
bind(String, Class, Type, Annotation[], Map<String, String[]>)
bind(RootParamNode, String, Class<?>, Type, Annotation[])
bind(String, Object, Map<String, String[]>)
bindBean(RootParamNode, String, Object)
unBind(Object, String)
getMessage(String, Object, Object...)
getStatus()
getJsonStatus()
enhance(ApplicationClass)
onTemplateCompilation(Template)
rawInvocation(Request, Response)
serveStatic(VirtualFile, Request, Response)
beforeDetectingChanges()
loadTemplate(VirtualFile)
detectChange()
detectClassesChange()
onApplicationStart()
afterApplicationStart()
onApplicationStop()
beforeInvocation()
afterInvocation()
onInvocationException(Throwable)
invocationFinally()
beforeActionInvocation(Method)
onActionInvocationResult(Result)
onInvocationSuccess()
onRequestRouting(Route)
afterActionInvocation()
onConfigurationRead()
onRoutesLoaded()
onEvent(String, Object)
onClassesChange(List<ApplicationClass>)
addTemplateExtensions()
addMimeTypes()
compileAll(List<ApplicationClass>)
routeRequest(Request)
modelFactory(Class<? extends Model>)
afterFixtureLoad()
postEvent(String, Object)
onApplicationReady()
compareTo(PlayPlugin)
overrideTemplateSource(BaseTemplate, String)
willBeValidated(Object)
```

And Play 2's is `play.api.Plugin`, which is very simple:

```
onStart(): Unit
onStop(): Unit
enabled: Boolean
```

Why are they so different? And I think the methods in plugin class of Play 1, are defined as `extension-points`, aren't they not needed anymore for Play 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play 2.0 differentiates *global settings* and *plugins*.

[**Global settings**](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.GlobalSettings) are specific to an application and allows to customize some behavior of the framework (e.g. what should be done if no action were found for a request). Actually most of the extension points of Play 1.x plugins are now in Play 2.x global settings.

[**Plugins**](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.Plugin) are modules which may need to be aware of the application lifecycle to perform initialization/cleaning operations.